# Appium: Could not find Automation.tracetemplate when running arc with XCode 6

Tags: appium

Running through the appium tutorial in the section "[Starting the Console](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/ios.html?ruby#starting-the-console)" for the pre-built iOS app,

I get a stack trace with the error "Could not find Automation.tracetemplate in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)"

This is using XCode 6 with the iOS 7.1 simulator installed

How do I point it to the correct location of Automation.tracetemplate?

Answer (score 0):

The .bundle extension is now .xrplugin in XCode 6.  The path can be changed under appium/lib/devices/ios/ios.js around line 749.

```
    var xcodeTraceTemplatePath = path.resolve(xcodeFolderPath,
      "../Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns",
      "AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources",
      "Automation.tracetemplate");
```

should be changed to

```
    var xcodeTraceTemplatePath = path.resolve(xcodeFolderPath,
      "../Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns",
      "AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources",
      "Automation.tracetemplate");
```

See the discussion here for more information on Appium with XCode 6: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/35_0RXJ2azc

Comment: "Could not find ios simulator binary" is another error which might require modification of ios.js for Appium to work with XCode 6